# Jquery .each, remove $(this)?

Tags: jquery, each

Assume a jquery `.each` loop:

```
function reverifyDiscounts() {
    //everything we need to verify a discount is already on the page. 
    //we'll remove the "bad" discounts when we submit the page
    console.info("Entering reverification");
    //event discounts are always valid once they're on the page because it's for the event
    $(".discountPromoItem").each(function () {
        //skip events
        if ($(this).attr("appliesto") == $("#hdnEventID").val()) {
            return true;
        }
        //we just need to make sure that the checkbox that the appliesto attribute references is checked!
        if (!$("checkbox[attribute$='" + $(this).attr("applitesto") + "']").is(":checked")) {
            //we also need to remove the promo code from the list of promo codes entered into the hidden textboxes
            $("#hdnAppliedPromoCode").val($("#hdnAppliedPromoCode").val().replace($(this).attr("code"), ""));
            //the item that it applies to is no longer selected and the promo must be removed
            $(this).remove(); //can't remove $(this) while inside the loop for whatever reason.
        }
    });
    recalculate();
}
```

Why does `$(this).remove()` fail or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can have only ONE element with a given ID in a document

Comment: Let me edit the code because I'm actually doing it on a class... hold on...

Comment: Please reproduce your problem in a fiddle.

Comment: The error can't be in your loop. I created a fiddle to check that: http://jsfiddle.net/zhrx7v2k/

Comment: You are also missing a closing `)` at the end

Comment: I've put in the actual code I'm using, should highlight the problem

Comment: @MetalPhoenix And what about a jsFiddle which replicates your issue? BTW, have you checked this is the `remove()` method the issue, not your condition? So the question is how do you debug it?

Comment: I did create a fiddle of a simplified version of this...http://jsfiddle.net/pwm3h233/1/

And it works.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix maybe your issue is because you are returning true if previous condition is true. But again, without seeing your issue, hard to tell what's going wrong. Anyway, seems easy to debug

Comment: I thought of that and have verified that it actually is not the problem. If I replace the .remove() line with an array.push and then iterate over the array post loop, it works. Code inside the loop gets executed exactly when it should

Comment: Unrelated, but you are also trying to use an attribute from the removed element. You may want to do that step before the `remove`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I've fixed it in my code.

Comment: Have added an alternate below, using `filter` and then `remove`. Can you try it?

Comment: If you do `console.log($(this));` before your remove statement, what does it show in console?

Comment: It gives me the object in firebug which I can mouseover, inspect. Etc. TrueBlueAussie suggested changing it to a filter with a .remove and it works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

Aside from a missing `)` at the end, your code actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hdc9ke9k/

The problem must be in the `if` test.

Try using a filter then do the remove last:

```
function reverifyDiscounts() {
    //everything we need to verify a discount is already on the page. 
    //we'll remove the "bad" discounts when we submit the page
    console.info("Entering reverification");
    //event discounts are always valid once they're on the page because it's for the event
    $(".discountPromoItem").filter(function () {
        //skip events
        if ($(this).attr("appliesto") == $("#hdnEventID").val()) {
            return false;
        }
        //we just need to make sure that the checkbox that the appliesto attribute references is checked!
        if (!$("checkbox[attribute$='" + $(this).attr("applitesto") + "']").is(":checked")) {
            $("#hdnAppliedPromoCode").val($("#hdnAppliedPromoCode").val().replace($(this).attr("code"), ""));
            return true;
        }
    }).remove();

    recalculate();
}
```

---

*Original code for original version of question*

An `each` with an ID selector makes no sense as an ID *must be unique* and only first one will match.

The reason for this is that browsers maintain a high-speed lookup dictionary of each ID vs a single DOM element. jQuery (and JavaScript) can only get the first match by ID.

Use classes instead for multiple item matching:

```
$(".thatThing").each(function(){ 
    if (someBoolCondition){
        $(this).remove(); 
    }

});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hdc9ke9k/

Comment: That's what I'm actually doing, I typed the id selector by habit. I've corrected the code to correct that.

Comment: In which case your code is correct, so the bug is likely in the `if` test. Can you show the rest of the real code?

Comment: I've put in the actual code I'm using, should highlight the problem. Interstingly, I tried making a fiddle of this in a simplified form and it works...

Comment: Aside from suggesting you move `$("#hdnEventID").val()` outside the loop, your code should work. Q: Not that it makes a difference, but why are you returning `true`?

Comment: It's a specific case: I'm checking all the rows of a table to see if they apply (with a single exception, the event which should always be ignored) and see if a corresponding checkbox is checked. If not, remove a row from a table and recalculate some things on the page.

Comment: Instead of an `each` and remove inside the loop, use a `filter` to find all the ones to remove, then apply the remove to the returned results (the ones that return `true` are retained by the filter).

Comment: That is the question that will keep us up late at night... It *should* have worked :)

Comment: All the same, thanks for the help on that. Wish I knew why. Also, TIL about .filter. :)

Comment: This is semi-correct. jQuery CAN return multiple elements having the same ID using $('[id="myId"]') - however, you STILL should never ever use an ID multiple times. That's not the purpose of an unique identifier.

Comment: @ChrisS. I mentioned an *ID selector* specifically. You have outlined an attribute selector, which is far slower and basically scans the entire DOM for matching text values. If you have to use that type of selector, you have more serious problems than those outlined above :)